# Matplotlib doesn't recognize Tkinter (NixOS 23.05)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, nixos

I've recently upgraded my NixOS version to 23.05, and found that Python's `matplotlib` doesn't recognize Tkinter.

```
Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr  4 2023, 22:10:32) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([0,1,2,3],[2,3,5,7])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2785, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2282, in gca
    return gcf().gca()
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 879, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 813, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 383, in new_figure_manager
    return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3570, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3575, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    return cls.FigureCanvas.new_manager(figure, num)
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1738, in new_manager
    return cls.manager_class.create_with_canvas(cls, figure, num)
  File "/nix/store/ba9xzs4rq19dwp96mxn98n3qm8krd2rc-python3-3.10.11-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 483, in create_with_canvas
    window = tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/nix/store/95cxzy2hpizr23343b8bskl4yacf4b3l-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /nix/store/ax09cbfj991hn856w1pmk68mxbf6lcfl-tcl-8.6.13/lib/tcl8.6/tk8.6 /nix/store/ax09cbfj991hn856w1pmk68mxbf6lcfl-tcl-8.6.13/lib/tk8.6 /nix/store/95cxzy2hpizr23343b8bskl4yacf4b3l-python3-3.10.11/lib/tk8.6 /nix/store/95cxzy2hpizr23343b8bskl4yacf4b3l-python3-3.10.11/lib/tk8.6 /nix/store/lib/tk8.6 /nix/store/95cxzy2hpizr23343b8bskl4yacf4b3l-python3-3.10.11/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

Here's a part of my current `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
#  vim # Do not forget to add an editor to edit configuration.nix! The Nano editor is also installed by default.
#  wget
  (python3.withPackages (p: with p; [
    pip
    matplotlib
    torch
    scipy
  ]))
  (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (p: with p; [
    random
  ]))
  gcc
];
```

However, I see that `tk.tcl` is in the directory `/nix/store/bqw3dmva266vi9y52ar5zy9kq5wpznfw-tk-8.6.13/lib/tk8.6`. Why is `matplotlib` looking for the wrong directories? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Not an answer, but it turns out upgrading NixOS to `unstable` channel solves the problem.